# Ajax call load datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ive a ajax call to send the data from a datepicker to my controller. 
this works well, but the page wont reload with the actual data from controller. 
how can i do it?

```
$(function () {
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'center',
            "showDropdowns": true,

        },
            function (start, end, label) {
            //alert("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            StartDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                EndDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "ActionLogs")',
                    data: { getstart: StartDate, getend: EndDate},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) { /*table.ajax.reload();*//*alert('Success');*/
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    },
                });
            });
    });
```

and then i have this code in controller, and i want to put the listlog2 data into datatable.

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Parse(getstart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(getend, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    List<ActionLogsViewModel> ListLogs = new List<ActionLogsViewModel>();
                    List<ActionLogsViewModel> ListLogs2 = new List<ActionLogsViewModel>();
                    _context.TBL_ActionsLogs.ToList().ForEach(a => ListLogs.Add(InitModel(a)));
                    foreach (var item in ListLogs)
                    {
                        if (item.CreateDate.Date > StartDate.Date && item.CreateDate.Date< EndDate.Date)
                        {
                            ListLogs2.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    return Json(ListLogs2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But, nothing happend to the page, wont reload.

Comment: what does your console log tell you? Does it give you any additional info? Why would you want to reload the page after a success? That kind of nullifies the use of making an Ajax call a little doesn't it?